# Error handling for a Patch and SubmitForm()

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

I have this formula inside the Submit Button:-

```
Patch('Printing Orders Details',
    ForAll(PrintOrderDetailsGallery.AllItems,
        {  ID: ID,
           Quantity: Value(PrintOrderQuantity.Text),
         'Quantity Each Artwork':PrintOrderQuantityForEachartwork.Text,
         'Network ID':PrintOrderNetworkComboBox.Selected.ID
        }
    )
);

SubmitForm(PrintOrderForm)
```

Which Patch some items and submit a form. but currently if the Patch raised an error, i will get an error message for each Patch (so if i have 5 items inside the ForAll, i will get 5 error messages)>> but at the same time the submit form will be executed,,, which will result in an inconsistent state of our data.. so how i can ensure that the Submit Form will only be executed if all the Patches inside the ForAll went successfully, if not to still show errors for each Patch ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Errors()` in Power Apps to to perform Error Handling for Patch function in Power Apps.

**Example**:

```
// create a new record in test scores list
Patch(
     'Test Scores',
     Defaults('Test Scores'),
     {
         TestName: txt_TestName.Text,
         StudentName: txt_StudentName.Text,
         Score: Value(txt_Score.Text)
     }
 );
 If(
     // check if there were any errors when the test score was submitted
     !IsEmpty(Errors('Test Scores')),
     // if true, show any error message
     Notify(
         Concat(Errors('Test Scores'), Column&": "&Message),
         NotificationType.Error
     ),
     // else, go to success screen
     Navigate('Success Screen');
 )
```

In your case, you can use `SubmitForm()` function inside `// else, go to success screen` block in above formula.

You can find more information related to this and other error handling ways at: [Power Apps Patch Function Error Handling](https://www.matthewdevaney.com/power-apps-patch-function-error-handling/)

Comment: thanks for the reply.. can i benifit from IfError() function also? as it seems more straightforward to use?

Comment: IfError function only tests conditions until it finds an error, it does not return any actual error messages. Check this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-iferror